# How to make UITextField respond when added in viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

In the parent view controller, I add a child view controller when the view loads:

```
// In the parent
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tokenFieldViewController = [[TokenFieldViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:self.tokenFieldViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tokenFieldViewController.view];
    self.tokenFieldViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.tokenFieldViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

In essence, this child view controller has a text field in its view:

```
// In the child
- (void) loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,99,99)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];
}
```

When coded like this, the text field is not tappable. That is, tapping it does not put a blinking cursor into it. However, when I add the child view controller in the parent's `viewDidAppear`, the text field starts working. I would like to know how to fix it for `viewDidLoad`, because I need the lifecycle of the child to match that of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that your only problem with the tapping is this line:

```
self.tokenFieldViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Between `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` there are a number of things going on.  The biggest of which is the measurement of views and subviews.  This happens between `viewWillLoadSubviews` and `viewDidLoadSubviews`.  You should not count on valid sizes until after `viewDidLoadSubviews`.

Override `viewDidLoadSubviews` and put your line in it, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.tokenFieldViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

Comment: There was no problem with `self.view.bounds`. It printed out as 320x436. After further investigation, I noticed that the top 44 points of the child view are not tappable. If I move the text field below 44, it starts working. There seems to be an invisible navigation bar blocking it. For some reason, this invisible bar is only present when the child controller is added in the parent's `viewDidLoad`, and not `viewDidAppear`. It should be noted that my parent view controller is wrapped in a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: That is really weird.  Is this in iOS 7? or build with XCode 5?

Comment: No, I'm still building for iOS 6 with XCode 4.6.